# Upgrading my jhipster application

Tags: java, mongodb, upgrade, jhipster

Why there is no upgrade jhipster application without regenerating all the entities, if it is there any anyone please let me know?

Comment: Do you mean *without* regenerating?

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 4):

This is just a workaround for your specific problem and not a general instruction.

JHipster provides an upgrade sub generator to upgrade the application.
You can run it on the JHipster app by running command `jhipster upgrade` this will upgrade the application and regenerate the entities and it is the recommended approach as there might be bug fixes and improvements on the entity code as well.

But if you really have to skip entities then the easiest way is to rename the `.jhipster` folder in your application root before you run the `jhipster upgrade` command. Once done rename it back.

This will remove some entries from your liquibase master.xml but I suggest you use git to restore then changes back

Comment: OK, I will try this lets see, how it goes, Thank you for answering.